# I'm not getting all the records for specific month

Tags: django

I'm trying to get all the posts from each month, like July has 11 and August has 1. But at this point when it loops I'm getting one of each month.

This will be the result:

```
2019 Aug (1) Time Lapse Video vs. Time Lapse Photo Test
Jul (11) A simple Tutorial about how to add Facebook login in your website.
```

This is my code on the template:

```
{% regroup events by timestamp.year as year_list %}
 {% for year in year_list %}
  {{ year.grouper }}
   {% regroup events by timestamp.month as month_list %}
    {% for month in month_list %}
     {{ month.list.0.timestamp|date:"M"}} ({{ month.list|length }})
      {% for post in events %}
       {% if post.timestamp == month.list.0.timestamp %}
           {{post.title}}<br>
       {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I expect to get the rest of month of July. thank you.

Comment: Well, you've specifically added a condition to only display the posts that exactly match the timestamp of the first post in the group; the only post that matches is itself. Why do you have that condition? `events` is already the list of posts in that month.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify: you should be iterating through `month.list`, not `events`.

Comment: Thank you Daniel Roseman. I took out that condition and iterating with month.list like. {% for post in month.list %} {{post.title}} {% endfor %} and it works perfect. Cheers.

Comment: Make sure to upvote helpful contributions to thank helpful users and increase their reputation.

Comment: Sorry I'm new here, how do I do that?Jon Hrovat

Comment: @AlmirPuglia If Daniel Roseman had posted his suggestion as an answer, you would be able to upvote it and mark it as accepted. However, he just posted it as a comment, so there is not much you can do besides upvoting his comment.

Comment: Got it,  thank you.